# Mysql select unique value + first occurrence + last occurence

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating a query that returns the following from a table containing transactions.
The table looks something like this:

```
id address_from address_to timestamp
```

So I want to create a list that contains:

All unique addresses and their first transaction and their last.

I have no problem selecting all unique addresses like this:

```
SELECT address_from as address 
  FROM transactions 
UNION 
SELECT address_to as address 
  FROM transactions
```

But how can I add the first timestamp that address appeared in either `address_from` or `address_to` and the last?
Some hints in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show sample data and your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT address, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
FROM ((SELECT address_from as address, timestamp 
       FROM transactions 
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT address_to as address, timestamp
       FROM transactions
      )
     ) a
GROUP BY address;
```

This has the timestamps for the addresses, but not the `id`s.  It is unclear which you are looking for.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I'm looking for. Been breaking my head over this for hours now... Thanks alot for this extremely quick answer. Will accept the answer in 4 minutes when I can.